# Issues while splitting blogger header into 2 parts

Tags: css, blogger

I am trying to split the blogger header into two parts. I googled about it and found some code. I added this code into the template:

```
<div id='header'>
<b:section class='blognames' id='blognames' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='yes'>
  <b:widget id='Header1' locked='true' title='all trick world (Header)' type='header'>
  ......................................
</b:section>
```

After this i added these two lines:

```
<b:section id='header-right' showaddelement='yes'/>
<div style='clear: both;'/>
```

Now, what code to write before ]]b:skin so that the header gets divided into two parts??

Answer (score 0):

It was a while back when I did that for my blog but as I remember all you need to do is change value for `maxwidget` attribute, something like this:

```
<b:section class='header' id='header' maxwidgets='2' showaddelement='yes'>
```